# GCM Push Notification Issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When the gcm push notification is sent, response shows successful, but at that time app was in stopped mode so msg must be queued, but when I restart the app gcm notification does'nt get received

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
```

The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_resqlife_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserChoice"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_choice"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegFormActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reg_form"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OTPVerificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_otpverification"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GooglePlayServicesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_google_play_services"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactsListActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".AlertActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alert"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".LocationService"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".NetworkActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_network"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateNetworkActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_network" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".NetworkActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".ReregisterGCMReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <data
                android:path="com.tpl.arpitgoyal.resqlife"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateProfile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update_profile" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NoInternetActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_no_internet"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InviteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_invite" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CoordinatesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_coordinates" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="maps.google.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
    <receiver
        android:name=".UnInstallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

            <data
                android:path="com.tpl.arpitgoyal.resqlife"
                android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SliderButtonActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_slider_button" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".VibratorService"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".SmsOTPVerificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sms_otpverification" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".OnLineService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: I did'nt set time_to_live for message, so it must be by default 4 weeks.

Comment: what do you mean that the app was in stopped mode? Also are you successfully receiving the message when the app is in the foreground?

Comment: yes i'm receiving messages when app is in foreground.By stop mode I meant that the app was force stopped.

Comment: Could you add your manifest to the question?

Comment: GcmBroadcastReceiver receives push messages.

Comment: Have a look at this manifest I think you need to adjust the way you define the GcmReceiver. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L26